# Inverse function on interval where it is one-to-one

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inverse-function

I have to find inverse function of

${\displaystyle{f(x)=\frac{\log x}{\log 2}+\frac{\log 2}{\log x}.}}$

${\displaystyle{y=\frac{\log x}{\log 2}+\frac{\log 2}{\log x}}}$

${\displaystyle{y=\frac{\log^2 x+\log^2 2}{\log 2\log x}}}$

${\displaystyle{y\log 2\log x={\log^2 x+\log^2 2}}}$

${\displaystyle{{\log^2 x+\log^2 2}}}-y\log 2\log x=0$

${\displaystyle{(\log x}-{\frac{y\log 2}{2})}^2-\frac{y^2}{4}\log 2\log x+\log 2\log x=0}$

${\displaystyle{(\log x}-{\frac{y\log 2}{2})}^2=\frac{y^2-4}{4}\log 2\log x}$

Could you help me with next step, please? Thanks for help.

Comment: I dont think there exists a way to define x in terms of y for such equations but I am not sure enough.....

Comment: What do you know about x range?

Comment: Range of $f(x)$ is $\left(-\infty,-2\right) or \left(2,\infty\right)$.

Comment: Do you mean the codomain?

Comment: Yes, you are right.

Answer (score 3):

Hint focused on simplification:

Let $h_{a}\left(x\right)$ denote the inverse of $g_{a}\left(x\right)=\frac{x}{a}+\frac{a}{x}$
where $a>0$.

Then the inverse of $f\left(x\right)=g_{a}\left(\log x\right)$
is $e^{h_{a}\left(x\right)}$.

Answer (score 2):

**HINT**

Start with finding the inverse of $g(x)=x+\frac 1 x$ (Notice that $f(x)=g(\frac {\log x} {log2})$ and you can easily find the inverse of $h(x)=\frac {\log x} {log2}$).

You have $f=g\circ h$ so $f^{-1}=h^{-1} \circ g^{-1}$

Comment: @drhab Slightly more simple, basically same idea.

Comment: Thanks to Eugen Covaci and drhab. So $f^-1=2^{\frac{1}{2}(x-\sqrt{x^2-4})$ on $x$ $\in (-\infty,-2) \cup (2,\infty)$ and  $f^{-1}=2^{\frac{1}{2}(x+\sqrt{x^2-4})$ on $x$ $\in (-2,2)$